# Как получить из строки числа?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить из строки числа?
Например, есть строка `str = 'Аня ходила по 3 этажу, там ее встретило 20 котов'`.
Получить `320` слитно у меня получилось, а как получить их в виде `3` и `20`? Получилось сделать массивом, может есть строковый метод??

Comment: `str.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужен строковый метод, напишите свой

```js
 var str = 'Аня ходила по 3 этажу, там ее встретило 20 котов';

 String.prototype.strFromNumb = function() {
   return  this.match(/\d+/g).map((item) => {
     return parseInt(item, 10);
   });
 }
 
 console.log(str.strFromNumb());

// Вывод => [3,20]
```